# Swift 3, NotificationCenter observer missing posted Notification

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, nsnotificationcenter

There seems to be a few changes surrounding the NotificationCenter in Swift 3 and I can't seem to quite get it right.

Using:

```
Apple Swift version 3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1)
```

I have a singleton object:

```
class Notifications {

    private static let pipeline = Notifications()
    ...
```

That receives and enqueues items subscribing to `NotificationsPipelineProtocol`. *(They are all pure swift, no Objective-C NSObjects here.)*

```
    private func enqueueNotification(_ notification: NotificationsPipelineProtocol) {
        ...
```

in which it adds itself as an observer to the NotificationCenter

```
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(Notifications.didReceiveNotificationCompletion(_:)),
                                       name: notification.completionNotificationName,
                                       object: notification)
```

**NOTE** - `notification.completionNotificationName` is a computed variable that produces a `Notification.Name` item.

But when the `NotificationsPipelineProtocol` item posts to the NotificationCenter:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: self.completionNotificationName, object: self)
```

The observer does not call it's associated subscribed method:

```
    @objc private func didReceiveNotificationCompletion(_ notification : Notification) {
    ...
```

Might you know why? Is there a way to check to see in NotificationCenter to which notifications a particular item is subscribed to? Is perhaps the singleton object dropping it's observation? Maybe the #selector has been improperly formatted?

XCode gives me no warnings or errors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `enqueueNotification` called? Is `notification` in `enqueueNotification` the object that is posting all of the notifications you want to observe?  Do you perhaps want the `object` parameter to be `nil`?

Comment: I construct a ''pipeline" aka a queue of Notifications, it is built there and confirmed to be in the pipeline. I'll try without including a reference to the object

Comment: It worked! I'm not sure why, might you know? Also if you post this as an answer, i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing the `NotificationPipelinesProtocol` object to `addObserver`.  This means that you will only receive notifications *posted by that object*.  If you want to receive notifications of the specified name posted by *any object* then you should pass `nil`:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(Notifications.didReceiveNotificationCompletion(_:)),
                                       name: notification.completionNotificationName,
                                       object: nil)
```

Comment: This tripped me up with the `addObserver(forName:object:queue:using:)` variant because I forgot that the `using` block automatically captures the observer.